# Getting different date format in server for cakephp3 datetime

Tags: php, timezone, cakephp-3.x

I am using cakephp3 for my website but its working differently on server. I am getting the datetime as `2018-07-12T06:27:49+00:00` with timezone offset but in server its returning as `2018-07-12T06:27:49`. Here the timezone offset is missing which is required.

Thanks

Comment: It's a string so just add it. Maybe it's omitted if it's GMT.

Comment: Its should be added automatically as i am using cake3 orm to make the query.

Comment: could you give information of your sql types and versions local & server?

Comment: I am using PHP Version 5.6.24. Server version: 5.6.38 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)